# Change the values of numberposts gallery

Tags: gallery

I have installed this plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-categories-2/)  to categorize my images.

In my functions.php I have put the following code to limit the number of images shown in the gallery:

```
function get_random_gallery_images(){
    global $wpdb,$post;
        $ids = "";
        $counter = 0;
        $number_of_posts = 1;
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

                if ($counter != 0) {
                    $ids .= ','.$attachment->ID;
                }
                else {
                    $ids .= $attachment->ID;
                }
                $counter++;
            }
        }
        return $ids;
}
```

in my single.php I have put the following code:

```
$attachment_ids = get_random_gallery_images();
$category_current = get_the_category($post->ID) ; //for getting the images of that specific category
echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="1" category="'.$category_current[0]->name.'" include="'.$attachment_ids.'" link="file"]');
```

The problem is that is does not matter if I change the values of numberposts. It always displays all of the images. What I am doing wrong? I only want to display 1 image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts`

So the `$args` for the `get_posts` would be like below and also the param for `post_status` is wrong. Check the codex for the details **[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters)**

Also when when you are fetching one attachment it is useless to set a counter for it. You can use the modified function

```
function get_random_gallery_images(){
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $ids = $attachment->ID;
        }
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

For more details check the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)**

Comment: I changed the $args code to post_per_page like you have mentioned, but it still displays all of the images. (removed the 'numberposts' => 1 )

Comment: can you debug and see what does the function `get_random_gallery_images()` returns, it should return one attachment id

Comment: I have debug on in my wp-config.php and I see no errors if fewing the post. (don't know how to to debug the specific function get_random_gallery_images()

Comment: you can user `var_dump($attachment_ids)` to see what it returns and why have you used the set of codes in `index.php`,

Comment: I am sorry. I cannot get it to work (I have very little knowledge of php) I don't know where to put the var_dump and how to read the results

Comment: Editted my question, did not put the code in index.php but in single.php. Also, I have put the <?php var_dump($attachment_ids) ?>   above my shortcode in single.php and the result is NULL

Comment: so it means `get_random_gallery_images()` has some issues, check and debug it

Comment: @Monique Modified the answer for the `get_random_gallery_images()`, check if this works

Comment: thanks for the update of the code. I have put in in my functions.php, but still it displays all the images. The var_dump still returns null.

Comment: can you check the posts if those have gallery images in them.

Comment: If I view the posts they display the images.